# How to access a variable that is inside a MovieClip timeline from the main timeline?

Tags: variables, scope, actionscript-2

I have a variable called toasters that is on the second frame of a MovieClip called shopMC, how can I acess the toasters variable from the first frame of the main timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shopMC.toasters won't exist until frame 2 starts for your movie.  I'd suggest keeping important data out of timelines keeping it on the main timeline or in a class or something instead.

_root.shopMC.toasters, to answer your question, would work from anywhere providing that shopMC had played at least one frame.